# MySQL query "more than one row"

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a mysql query below

```
SELECT `company`,`type`,`code` FROM `location` WHERE (
SELECT code FROM meter WHERE `meter`.`location_code`=location.code AND meter.code NOT IN (
SELECT meter_code FROM reading
))
```

I receive an error saying that more than one row is returned

Can I ask why/have guidance

Other questions haven't really helped me to be honest

Comment: i gues you mean; SELECT `company`,`type`,`code` FROM `location` WHERE code in (
SELECT code FROM meter WHERE `meter`.`location_code`=location.code AND meter.code NOT IN (
SELECT meter_code FROM reading
))
Mysql now expects the result of the first subquery to be true or false, not a collection of codes.

Comment: can there be more than 1 meter at a location?

Comment: @xqbert Nope. I'm reading that it should ideally be INNER JOIN on other answers but they all seem so messy

Comment: @Dennisvdh nope - the end result is that its meant to bring out a list of meters that haven't got a reading, that unfortunately gives out no result

Comment: could you please provide your table structure?

Comment: More than one row is returned. It creates an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need data from meter or meter code

```
SELECT `company`,`type`,`code` 
FROM `location` 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM meter 
              LEFT JOIN Reading R
                on meter.code = R.meter_Code
              WHERE `meter`.`location_code`=location.code 
                and R.meter_Code is null
             )
```

or to keep with the theme of using exists  (this avoids performance impact of distinct and avoids the joins; but a not exists can be slow.

```
SELECT `company`,`type`,`code` 
FROM location l 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM meter m
              WHERE m.location_code=l.code 
                and not exists (SELECT * 
                                FROM READING r
                                WHERE R.meter_Code = m.Code

             )
```

This is how it could be done with joins, but the distinct and joins seem like they could be costly.  distinct is necessary as I assume a location may have many meters or vice versa or a meter may have many readings which cause the data to be multiplied  thus distinct; but at a cost.

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.company,l.type,l.code
FROM location l
INNER JOIN METER M
 on l.code = m.location_Code
LEFT JOIN reading R
 on R.Meter_Code = m.Code
WHERE r.meter_Code is null
```

Would need to test each to find what performance best suits your need.  record count in each table indexes and data distribution could all change the performance of each of these.  I'm partial to the last one, then first one from a maintenance standpoint but it could be the worst in performance.

Comment: Stuck with this for a week!! Saviour.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT `company`,`type`,`code` 
FROM `location` 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT code 
              FROM meter 
              WHERE `meter`.`location_code` = location.code AND 
                     meter.code NOT IN (SELECT meter_code FROM reading))
```